# Cannot verify JWT Token with cookie to load the 'Dashboard page' in NodeJs. How should i fix it?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, cookies, jwt

I am creating a MERN stack web application (without ReactJs) which will allow the user to access the 'Dashboard' page once it logs in and cookie is generated, I need to verify the JWT Token with that of the cookie, The Cookie is generated successfully but the Dashboard page is coming blank. ( More specifically "{}" : this message on the Dashboard page) Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have included the JWT and Cookie Parser module and initialized its middlewares as well

Here is the Dashboard route code

```
router.get("/dashboard", auth , function(req,res){
     console.log(`Cookies. ${req.cookies.jwt}`)
    res.render("dashboard");
})
```

the auth is imported from auth.js and is defined in my server file

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken"); //Importing JWT Tokens
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const registrationData = require("../models/registration"); //Importing Registration Page Models & Schemas

const auth = async function(req,res, next){

    try{
        console.log("Dashboard Page reached\n");
        const Usertoken = req.cookies.jwtLogin;
        console.log(` Cookies token dashboard ${Usertoken}`)
        const verifyUser = jwtLogin.verify(Usertoken, process.env.SECRET_KEY);
        console.log("Dashboard Route Reached\n");
        next();


    } catch(error){

        res.status(401).send(error);
    }
}

module.exports = auth;
```

Here is app.post login code of server.js which contains JWTLogin Cookie

```
app.post('/login', async function (req, res) {

    try { 

        const email = req.body.email;
        const password = req.body.password;
        const emailIsMatch = await registrationData.findOne({ email }); //Verfying Email from Database 

        const passwordIsMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, emailIsMatch.password); // Verifying Password from Databases

        // Generating tokens via middleware

        const token = await emailIsMatch.generateAuthToken();
        console.log("Email JWT Token is generated via route/login. Token << " + token);

        // Set Cookie based on jwt token

        res.cookie("jwtLogin", token, {

            expires: new Date(Date.now() + 900000),
            httpOnly: true
            // secure: true
        });

        console.log(`Cookie for User Login Generated. ${req.cookies.jwtLogin}`)

        if (passwordIsMatch) {
            res.status(201).render("index");
        }

        else {
            res.send("Invalid Login Details");
        }
    }

    catch (error) {
        res.status(400).send(error);
    }

});
```

Here is the code of login route wherein i have set the jwtLogin cookie

```
app.post('/login', async function (req, res) {

    try {

        //  Storing users login data from login page 

        const email = req.body.email;
        const password = req.body.password;
        const emailIsMatch = await registrationData.findOne({ email }); //Verfying Email from Database 

        const passwordIsMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, emailIsMatch.password); // Verifying Password from Databases

        // Generating tokens via middleware

        const token = await emailIsMatch.generateAuthToken();
        console.log("Email JWT Token is generated via route/login. Token << " + token);

        // Set Cookie based on jwt token

        res.cookie("jwtLogin", token, {

            expires: new Date(Date.now() + 900000),  //  Test Cookie expires in 15minutes
            httpOnly: true
            // secure: true
        });

        console.log(`Cookie for User Login Generated. ${req.cookies.jwtLogin}`)

        if (passwordIsMatch) {
            res.status(201).render("index");
        }

        else {
            res.send("Invalid Login Details");
        }
    }

    catch (error) {
        res.status(400).send(error);
    }

    // const user = new loginData(req.body);
    // user.save().then(function(){
    //     res.status(201).send(user);
    // }).catch(function(error){
    //     res.status(400).send(error);
    // })
    // console.log(user);
});
```

I can see the cookies on the browser's tab, and after login, i manually go and visit the dashboard page on /dashboard route. I do not get any error, but the only output i get is

{}

Thank you so much for reading through all this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much in advance!!

Comment: I forgot to mention. In Auth.js i added several console.log statements to see where the error was. And i found that only first console.log is executed and from second line in try block is not executing . I hope this helps.